# How can I enable firacode ligature on gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

I have installed firacode from `sudo apt install fonts-firacode` as instructed here(https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Linux-instructions#installing-with-a-package-manager) and selected in the terminal preferences.

[image]

But can not find option to enable the ligatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot because gnome terminal doesn't support them.

You can use kitty, konsole, or any of other options to do so... But, you cannot use gnome terminal.

Comment: Not in favor of going to install different DE tools along with new bunch of dependcies. I willl consider it solution, thanks for informing

Comment: @tbhaxor Yeah, I don't like it either myself just more package bloat, but it's the honest answer. Kitty is probably the smallest terminal to support it with the least dependencies. Kitty does not work in Wayland though, where Konsole does. Not my idea though, I hate that it has to be that way I'm just passing it along. :D